# How can I find out what's wrong with mysqli extension?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using `PHP 5.6.30` and I need `mysqli` extension. In `php.ini` I have

```
extension_dir = "ext"
...
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

`ext` dir exists in folder where php is installed, and  `php_mysqli.dll` exists in either `ext` folder and in php install folder. `php -m` shows that mysqli is installed. Still the following code

```
new mysqli ( 'localhost', 'root', 'root', 'db_name_here');
```

outputs `Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found`

The question is: how can I find out what's wrong with `mysqli`

**UPD.** I'm using `Win7` and the server is `Apache 2.4`

Comment: First guess: You checked one `php.ini` file but not the one used by your web site, or maybe you are using the PHP CLI ? That often uses a different `php.ini` to the one used by the web site

Comment: please check your `extension_dir` path. It should be fully qualified. i.e extension_dir = "D:/wamp/php/ext"

Comment: @RiggsFolly how can I find out what `.ini` file is used? And no, I'm not calling `php` from `cmd`.

Comment: @NishantNair Bit of a leap into the dark A) Thinking he is a windows user and B) assuming he is using WAMPServer

Comment: Create a little script `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` run it and look at the `Loaded Configuration File` setting in the first section of the output

Comment: @RiggsFolly my mistake I would have asked him that first.

Comment: Actually, your previous questions have been based on a *nix OS so why have you got a DLL mentioned in `extension=php_mysqli.dll` should that be `extension=php_mysqli.so`

Comment: @NishantNair Not necesarily a mistake, just a leap of faith!

Comment: Have updated the question. I'm using `Win7` and the server is `Apache 2.4`

Comment: Manually installed? Or are you using WAMPServer or XAMPP or something like that

Comment: @NishantNair :) :) You were right all the time

Comment: @RiggsFolly I saw the .dll file so I had commented on it guessing as windows as an OS

Comment: @RiggsFolly Apache was installed manually, i.e. downloaded, configured and installed with `httpd -k install`

Comment: Then @NishantNair May well be right. Make sure the `extension_dir = "C:/is/fully/qualified/ext"`

Comment: Let us know if that works please

Comment: @RiggsFolly, NishantNair specifying full path helped!!! Thank you! Please write it in separate answer, so that I can plus that an accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also check if the library is loaded or not in your env

```
  if (extension_loaded('mysqli') && function_exists('mysqli_init')) {
   echo "having lib";
  }else{
  echo "No library loaded or exist";
  }
```

Also you can specify fully qualified path for extension_dir.

Check your extension_dir path. It should be fully qualified. i.e

```
   extension_dir = "C:/wamp/php/ext" // your php path folder.
```

Comment: Except he already knows its not loaded because he gets an error saying so!

Comment: @RiggsFolly using this function we can check if the mysqli is intialized or loaded.

Comment: Keep the answer, and if he replies that the fully pathed extension_dir fixes it make that your answer and you will get my UV

Comment: @RiggsFolly Good to hear that.

Comment: As the OP has gone very quiet I think we can assume that fixing the `extension_dir` has probably worked. Make that your answer and I will UV

Comment: specifying full path helped! Thank you!

Comment: Yippee another satisfied customer

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you...! Cheers

Comment: @Eugeny89 Thanks a Lot.

Comment: @RiggsFolly still I'm having the same issue with curl extension. Do you have an idea of what that can be?

Comment: @NishantNair still I'm having the same issue with curl extension. Do you have an idea of what that can be?